# Badge progress trackers

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I think it'd be cool to be able to go to

https://security.stackexchange.com/badges/

then click on one of the badges like

https://security.stackexchange.com/badges/58/sportsmanship

and see what progress you've made towards getting that specific badge.

Since badges are supposed to encourage participation in the community, a simple graphical way to track that would be good I think.

Any thoughts?

Comment: There is a [data.se] query for that, I'll try to dig it up later...

Comment: Oooh. These are pretty cool and i knew not of their availability! But that would still require me to go there, plug in my UID and run the query. Why not just show the progress when i'm on the badges page?

Comment: @D3C4FF: Most of the queries will auto insert your uid if you're logged in. They're not up to date. The database is dumped every few months, cleaned out, and then imported into the Data Explorer for queries.

Answer (score 1):

How about [Stinking Badges](http://agent86ix.github.io/stackapps/badge)? That lists badge progress for some badges.

You can find queries for most badges on [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/), but that runs on database dumps that are updated biweekly(I think).

For example, [this is the query for the Sportsmanship badge](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/107399/sportsmanship-badge-progress)

Comment: Aside from the its not upto date with the time, it only shows a few different badges... :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will definitely help increase participation in the community but the only issue I can think of is that we can not have a generic pattern for all the badges. e.g. some badges are awarded when the user reads the complete FAQ or when bounties are awarded or the first down vote.You will find many such cases where the progress of a badge can not be measured.

For some review badges one can see the badge progress in the stats tab under reviews. Similarly you can see your `Research-assistant` badge progress after completing a tag-wiki edit.